# Can't reassemble RAID 1 after switching motherboard

Tags: raid, mdadm

I just swapped the motherboard, CPU, and RAM in my server computer, and I was really hoping the RAID would just work when I booted back up. However, the RAID will not appear and mdadm doesn't even seem to remember it.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
unused devices: <none>
```

However, there still appears to be a record of the RAID in the mdadm.conf file:

```
$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Wed, 25 Mar 2020 15:22:26 -0600 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=clover:0 UUID=87dda574:9a1f83c3:4433dd3a:4b3d9847
```

I've tried all the assemble and scan commands I can find, but nothing works

Also, here's what mdadm examine says:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-z]
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    250066944 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

I do have all my data backed up, but it would just be much simpler to just reassemble the raid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Was Windows somehow involved at all in this?  Googling around, this problems appears to crop up when Windows does something funny with the hard drives.

Comment: @BrianTurek Not directly. I pulled the motherboard (with the CPU and RAM) out of a windows pc, but I wouldn't think that would make any difference. After hours of no progress, I finally just reformatted the drives and created a RAID. However, I kept noticing that when I'd create a raid with the entire drive (vs raid on drive partitions) the raid would disappear every time I'd reboot and it would show the have behavior as I described above. I'm thinking there's some BIOS feature (like Secure Boot or something)  that messed it up in the first place. But who knows; that's just my guess.

Comment: I’m in this very same scenario right now. Were you able to rebuild your RAID setup? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: @ThankYouRob Eventually I just decided it wasn't worth the time of trying to figure out reassembling it, so I just reformatted and then copied all my data back on from another backup. Sorry I can't be of more help!